# What't the different between 'HTTP/1.1 200' and 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'

Tags: http

When I telnet two servers htu571 and htu577, I got the following results :

--htu571--->

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
.....
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2013 23:39:58 GMT
Connection: close
```

--htu577--->

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
.......
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2013 23:43:51 GMT
Connection: close
```

---

You can see there is no 'OK' in htu571's log, what is the problem here?

Comment: It's the same, 200 is the HTTP code for a successful request.

Comment: OK is an optionnal message.

Answer (score 3):

There's no significant difference. All that matters for the protocol is the numeric reply code. Everything after that is just commentary that might be displayed to the human user, but it's ignored by the application. Since `200` responses are for successful downloads, and the document is displayed to the user with no error message, there's no real need for this text, although it's normal to include it for the benefit of users monitoring the traffic for debugging reasons.

Comment: one of our functions must use '200 OK' to identify the server is connected, how can I change something in the server's configuration so that I can get the message '200 OK' instead of '200'?